# Younow onLoad (with greasemonkey)

Tags: javascript, onload

when loading the younow website the messagebox "Start" pops up twice. -How can I fix this?

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        test
// @include   https://www.younow.com/*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// @require http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==
$(document).ready(function() { 
alert("Start");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `alert` acts this way on this website, maybe because of a reload after the call, but with a prepend it's ok for me.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('body').prepend("toto"); // your code here
});
```

Also you don't need to use the ready function, greasmonkey start your script at the right time.

But the problem is:

1. I suppose you want to do your stuff when all ajax elements are loaded. So the best way to do it is to observe the dom.
2. Since the web site change the current page using AJAX requests on clicking and the `hashchange` event doesn't work, I use some trick to listen any page change.

With this script you can use an `alert` function:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        test
// @include   https://www.younow.com/*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// @require https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

var observer = null;
initObserver();

function initObserver()
{
  observer = new MutationObserver(onMutation);
  observer.observe(document,
  {
    childList: true, // report added/removed nodes
    subtree: true,   // observe any descendant elements
  });
}

$(window).on('hashchange', function(e)
{
     initObserver();
});

intervalMutation = setInterval(onMutation.bind(null, null), 1000);

function locationObserver()
{
  var oldLocation = location.href;
   setInterval(function() {
        if(location.href != oldLocation) {
             onMutation(null);
             oldLocation = location.href
        }
    }, 1000); // check every second
}
locationObserver();

function onMutation(mutations)
{
  // Check if this class exits:
  if($('.trending-now').length ||
     $('.ynicon ynicon-chat').length ||
     $('.trending_title').length ||
     $('.trending-tags-list').length)
  {
     // Disconnect the observer:
     observer.disconnect();
     // Clear the interval :
     clearInterval(intervalMutation);
     // Call your code:
     pageReady();
  }
}

function pageReady()
{
  // your code here:
  alert('start');
}
```